# Structuring IF, AND, OR for two sets of two conditions

Tags: excel

I'm trying to fix a formula:

`=IF(OR(C4="", F4=""), "-", IF(OR(AND(C4="Yes", VLOOKUP(F4, Table, 2)>=4), AND(D4>=10, VLOOKUP(F4, Table, 2)>=4)), "Yes", "-"))`

Essentially, if one of two sets of two conditions are met, then Yes, if not then, nothing.

Error I get is #NAME?

Comment: What is the formula doing that is wrong?

Comment: I just get a general error pop-up; i'm thinking that the sequence of ORs and ANDs may not be correct, but each way I try it I still get the same error

Comment: `=IF(OR(C4="", F4=""), "-", IF(OR(AND(C4="Yes", VLOOOKUP(F4, Table, 2)>=4), AND(D4>=10, VLOOKUP(F4, Table, 2)>=4)), "Yes", "-")`?

Comment: Nope; when I review the formula, the first condition (C4+Vlookup) is caught by the AND function, however the second condition is caught by the OR function

Comment: There might be chances that the value that u lookup might not be present in the range that you search which could return the error

Comment: Or use the forth criterion in both your vlookups `VLOOOKUP(F4, Table, 2,0)>=4)`

Comment: just noticed, VLOOOKUP, one too many "O"; thanks for your help